# Sprytabs no longer working after i change hoverintent to mouseevent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just changed a dropdown menu to trigger on mouseevent, but i have some sprytabs nestled within the dropcontent that are now no longer working. The only thing i changed was

this (in which my tabs were working fine)

```
$(function(){
        $('#navigation_horiz').delay(50).fadeIn(50);
        $('#navigation_horiz').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: 'auto',  //the default width of drop down elements
        slideDownDuration: 500, //easing duration for slideDown
        slideUpDuration: 200 //easing duration for slideUp    
        });
});
```

to this (now tabs no longer working nestled in drop content)

```
$(function(){
    $('#navigation_horiz ul li').bind('mouseenter',function(e){
        $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if($(this).children('.dropdown').length>0){
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id',$(this).children('.dropdown').attr('id'));            
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').html($(this).children('.dropdown').html());
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').slideDown(500);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().css('opacity',0);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().animate({opacity:0},0).animate({opacity:1},1000,'linear');
        }
    });

    $('#navigation_horiz').bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
        $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').delay(500).slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

anyone see an issue on what is needed to fix this?

Comment: Are there any error messages you should share with us? Or does it still compile but simply doesn't work as expected?

Comment: the entire menu works fine, all other content displays fine, if I add back the original script noted above, sprytabs work fine, then put in the mouseeneter, mouseleave script and sprytabs stop working ..... here is site URL http://www21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/69528  sprytabs located under the "Players" menu

Comment: set up 2 demos http://jsfiddle.net/7aSDS/15/  this one has tabs working , and this one does not after i use mouseevent http://jsfiddle.net/7aSDS/14/   I have no idea why the tabs would stop working ? Both using exact same HTML and CSS , only difference is the script

Comment: i checked both the fiddles and both are working fine over here.
what different you are using i am not getting here.

Comment: are you sure the tabs are working on both ? I just doubled checked in IE, FF and Chrome, and it is not working at all on the version with the mouse event , try clicking the tabs the open in the players drop down and see if any images change